# SF Symbol does not work well with scaleAspectFill

Tags: uiimageview, sf-symbols, contentmode

I noticed that SF symbol doesn't really work well with `scaleAspectFill`.

For instance, given a circular aspect fill UIImageView with a thin border, setting its image to `UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")` would look like the following. Notice the image doesn't extend all the way to the edge.

[image]

Setting the image to `UIImage(systemName: "person.fill")` would look like this. Somehow it messes up the auto layout height constraint (this is the case even when contentMode is set to `center`).

[image]

My workaround is to export SF symbol as png and load them into Xcode, but this is not ideal of course. Am I using SF symbols incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we create a `UIImage` with an SF Symbol, it gets a vector backing and the image behaves much more like a font character than an image.

It will be much easier to understand if we skip the `cornerRadius` for now.

For example, if I set the text of a label to `O` and give it a yellow background, it will look like this:

[image]

The character does not reach to the edges of the bounding box.

So, when we use: `let thisImage = UIImage(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")` and set an image view's image, we get this:

[image]

As we see, there is "padding" on all 4 sides.

To "remove" the padding, we can convert the `CGImage` backing to a `UIImage` ... but we need to keep a few things in mind.

So, 6 examples - each example is a subclass of this "base" controller:

```
class MyBaseVC: UIViewController {

    let imgViewA = UIImageView()
    let imgViewB = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [imgViewA, imgViewB].forEach { v in
            // use AspectFill
            v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
            // background color so we can see the framing
            v.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            imgViewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            imgViewA.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            imgViewA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
            imgViewA.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgViewA.widthAnchor),
            
            imgViewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgViewA.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imgViewB.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            imgViewB.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160.0),
            imgViewB.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgViewB.widthAnchor),
            
        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

The first example just shows the layout with empty yellow-background image views:

```
class Example1VC: MyBaseVC {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

and it looks like this:

[image]

The 2nd example create an image from "person.crop.circle.fill" and sets the first image view:

```
class Example2VC: MyBaseVC {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nm = "person.crop.circle.fill"
        
        // create UIImage from SF Symbol at "default" size
        guard let imgA = UIImage(systemName: nm)?.withTintColor(.lightGray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) else {
            fatalError("Could not load SF Symbol: \(nm)!")
        }
        print("imgA size:", imgA.size)
        imgViewA.image = imgA
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

So far, nothing you haven't seen yet.

The code also output the generated image size to the debug console... in this case, `imgA size: (20.0, 19.0)`

So, we save out that image as a 20x19 png and load it into the 2nd image view:

```
class Example3VC: MyBaseVC {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let nm = "person.crop.circle.fill"
        
        // create UIImage from SF Symbol at "default" size
        guard let imgA = UIImage(systemName: nm)?.withTintColor(.lightGray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) else {
            fatalError("Could not load SF Symbol: \(nm)!")
        }

        guard let imgB = UIImage(named: "imgA20x19") else {
            fatalError("Could not load imgA20x19")
        }
        
        print("imgA:", imgA.size, "imgB:", imgB.size)
        
        imgViewA.image = imgA
        imgViewB.image = imgB
    }
}
```

As expected, because its now a bitmap instead of vector data, it gets unacceptably fuzzy... and, we're still not to the edges:

[image]

So, for the 4th example, we'll use the `.cgImage` backing data from the generated SF Symbol image to effectively create the bitmap version "on-the-fly":

```
class Example4VC: MyBaseVC {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let nm = "person.crop.circle.fill"

        // create UIImage from SF Symbol at "default" size
        guard let imgA = UIImage(systemName: nm)?.withTintColor(.lightGray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) else {
            fatalError("Could not load SF Symbol: \(nm)!")
        }
        
        // get a cgRef from imgA
        guard let cgRef = imgA.cgImage else {
            fatalError("Could not get cgImage!")
        }
        // create imgB from the cgRef
        let imgB = UIImage(cgImage: cgRef, scale: imgA.scale, orientation: imgA.imageOrientation)
            .withTintColor(.lightGray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        
        print("imgA:", imgA.size, "imgB:", imgB.size)
        
        imgViewA.image = imgA
        imgViewB.image = imgB
    }
}
```

[image]

Getting closer... the image now reaches the edges, but is still blurry.

To fix that, we'll use a "point" configuration when we generate the initial SF Symbol image:

```
class Example5VC: MyBaseVC {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let nm = "person.crop.circle.fill"
        
        // create UIImage from SF Symbol at "160-pts" size
        let cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 160.0)
        guard let imgA = UIImage(systemName: nm, withConfiguration: cfg)?.withTintColor(.lightGray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) else {
            fatalError("Could not load SF Symbol: \(nm)!")
        }
        
        // get a cgRef from imgA
        guard let cgRef = imgA.cgImage else {
            fatalError("Could not get cgImage!")
        }
        // create imgB from the cgRef
        let imgB = UIImage(cgImage: cgRef, scale: imgA.scale, orientation: imgA.imageOrientation)
            .withTintColor(.lightGray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        
        print("imgA:", imgA.size, "imgB:", imgB.size)
        
        imgViewA.image = imgA
        imgViewB.image = imgB
    }
}
```

The debug size output shows `imgB: (159.5, 159.5)` (so, pretty close to 160x160 size of the image view), and it looks like this:

[image]

We now have a crisp rendering, without the "padding" ... and we can add the corner radius and border:

```
class Example6VC: MyBaseVC {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let nm = "person.crop.circle.fill"
        
        // create UIImage from SF Symbol at "160-pts" size
        let cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 160.0)
        guard let imgA = UIImage(systemName: nm, withConfiguration: cfg)?.withTintColor(.lightGray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) else {
            fatalError("Could not load SF Symbol: \(nm)!")
        }
        
        // get a cgRef from imgA
        guard let cgRef = imgA.cgImage else {
            fatalError("Could not get cgImage!")
        }
        // create imgB from the cgRef
        let imgB = UIImage(cgImage: cgRef, scale: imgA.scale, orientation: imgA.imageOrientation)
            .withTintColor(.lightGray, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        
        print("imgA:", imgA.size, "imgB:", imgB.size)
        
        imgViewA.image = imgA
        imgViewB.image = imgB
        
        [imgViewA, imgViewB].forEach { v in
            v.layer.cornerRadius = 80
            v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            v.layer.borderWidth = 1
        }
    }
    
}
```

Example 6 result:

[image]

As you mentioned in your post, you'll notice the top image view is not exactly round -- that is, it somehow lost its 1:1 ratio.

This is a quirky side-effect of using SF Symbols as images that I have long since given up trying to understand. Different symbols will cause the image view to change size, regardless of constraints.

You can see some discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66293917/6257435