# Stroke image border in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to recreate Apple's festival lights image in SwiftUI (screenshot from Apple India's website). Expected result:

[image: Apple India Diwali logo]

Here's what I've managed to achieve so far:

[image]

MY UNDERSTANDING SO FAR: Images are not Shapes, so we can't stroke their borders, but I also found that shadow() modifier places shadows on image borders just fine. So, I need a way to customize the shadow somehow and understand how it works.

WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR: Besides the code above, I tried to unsuccessfully convert a given SF Symbol to a `Shape` using Vision framework's contour detection, based on my understanding of this article: https://www.iosdevie.com/p/new-in-ios-14-vision-contour-detection

Can someone please guide me on how I would go about doing this, preferably using SF symbols only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `Vision` framework with `VNDetectContourRequestRevision1` to get a `cgPath`:

```
func detectVisionContours(from sourceImage: UIImage) -> CGPath? {
    
    let inputImage = CIImage.init(cgImage: sourceImage.cgImage!)
    
    let contourRequest = VNDetectContoursRequest.init()
    contourRequest.revision = VNDetectContourRequestRevision1
    contourRequest.contrastAdjustment = 1.0
    contourRequest.maximumImageDimension = 512
    
    let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler.init(ciImage: inputImage, options: [:])
    try! requestHandler.perform([contourRequest])
    if let contoursObservation = contourRequest.results?.first {
        return contoursObservation.normalizedPath
    }
    
    return nil
}
```

The path will be based on a `0,0 1.0,1.0` coordinate space, so to use it we need to scale the path to our desired size. It also uses inverted Y-coordinates, so we'll need to flip it also:

```
    // cgPath returned from Vision will be in rect 0,0 1.0,1.0 coordinates
    //  so we want to scale the path to our view bounds
    let scW: CGFloat = targetRect.bounds.width / cgPth.boundingBox.width
    let scH: CGFloat = targetRect.bounds.height / cgPth.boundingBox.height
    
    // we need to invert the Y-coordinate space
    var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        .scaledBy(x: scW, y: -scH)
        .translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -cgPth.boundingBox.height)
    
    return cgPth.copy(using: &transform)
```

Couple notes...

When using `UIImage(systemName: "applelogo")`, we get an image with "font" characteristics - namely, empty space. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71743787/6257435 and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66293917/6257435 for some discussion.

So, we ***could*** use it directly, but it makes the path scaling and translation a bit complex.

So, instead of this "default":

[image]

we can use a little code to "trim" the space for a more usable image:

[image]

Then we can use the path from `Vision` as the path of a `CAShapeLayer`, along with these layer properties: `.lineCap = .round` / `.lineWidth = 8` / `.lineDashPattern = [2.0, 20.0]` (for example) to get a "dotted line" stroke:

[image]

Then we can use that same path on a shape layer as a mask on a gradient layer:

[image]

and finally remove the image view so we see only the view with the masked gradient layer:

[image]

Here's example code to produce that:

```
import UIKit
import Vision

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let myOutlineView = UIView()
    let myGradientView = UIView()
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    let defaultImageView = UIImageView()
    let trimmedImageView = UIImageView()

    var defaultImage: UIImage!
    var trimmedImage: UIImage!
    
    var visionPath: CGPath!

    // an information label
    let infoLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        // get the system image at 240-points (so we can get a good path from Vision)
        //  experiment with different sizes if the path doesn't appear smooth
        let cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 240.0)
        
        // get "applelogo" symbol
        guard let imgA = UIImage(systemName: "applelogo", withConfiguration: cfg)?.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) else {
            fatalError("Could not load SF Symbol: applelogo!")
        }
        // now render it on a white background
        self.defaultImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imgA.size).image { ctx in
            UIColor.white.setFill()
            ctx.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imgA.size))
            imgA.draw(at: .zero)
        }

        // we want to "strip" the bounding box empty space
        // get a cgRef from imgA
        guard let cgRef = imgA.cgImage else {
            fatalError("Could not get cgImage!")
        }
        // create imgB from the cgRef
        let imgB = UIImage(cgImage: cgRef, scale: imgA.scale, orientation: imgA.imageOrientation)
            .withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        
        // now render it on a white background
        self.trimmedImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imgB.size).image { ctx in
            UIColor.white.setFill()
            ctx.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imgB.size))
            imgB.draw(at: .zero)
        }

        defaultImageView.image = defaultImage
        defaultImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(defaultImageView)

        trimmedImageView.image = trimmedImage
        trimmedImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(trimmedImageView)
        
        myOutlineView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(myOutlineView)
        
        myGradientView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(myGradientView)
        
        // next step button
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Next Step", for: [])
        btn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        btn.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(btn)
        
        infoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(infoLabel)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // inset default image view 20-points on each side
            //  height proportional to the image
            //  near the top
            defaultImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            defaultImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            defaultImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            defaultImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: defaultImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: defaultImage.size.height / defaultImage.size.width),
            
            // inset trimmed image view 40-points on each side
            //  height proportional to the image
            //  centered vertically
            trimmedImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            trimmedImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            trimmedImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            trimmedImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: self.trimmedImage.size.height / self.trimmedImage.size.width),
            
            // add outline view on top of trimmed image view
            myOutlineView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myOutlineView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myOutlineView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myOutlineView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // add gradient view on top of trimmed image view
            myGradientView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myGradientView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myGradientView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myGradientView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // button and info label below
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: defaultImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            infoLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trimmedImageView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            infoLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 60.0),
            
        ])
        
        // setup the shape layer
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        
        // this will give use round dots for the shape layer's stroke
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 8
        shapeLayer.lineDashPattern = [2.0, 20.0]
        
        // setup the gradient layer
        let c1: UIColor = .init(red: 0.95, green: 0.73, blue: 0.32, alpha: 1.0)
        let c2: UIColor = .init(red: 0.95, green: 0.25, blue: 0.45, alpha: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.colors = [c1.cgColor, c2.cgColor]
        
        myOutlineView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        myGradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(nextStep), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
        guard let pth = pathSetup()
        else {
            fatalError("Vision could not create path")
        }
        self.visionPath = pth
        
        shapeLayer.path = pth
        
        gradientLayer.frame = myGradientView.bounds.insetBy(dx: -8.0, dy: -8.0)
        let gradMask = CAShapeLayer()
        gradMask.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        gradMask.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradMask.lineCap = .round
        gradMask.lineWidth = 8
        gradMask.lineDashPattern = [2.0, 20.0]
        
        gradMask.path = pth
        gradMask.position.x += 8.0
        gradMask.position.y += 8.0
        gradientLayer.mask = gradMask
        
        nextStep()
    }
    
    var idx: Int = -1
    
    @objc func nextStep() {
        idx += 1
        switch idx % 5 {
        case 1:
            defaultImageView.isHidden = true
            trimmedImageView.isHidden = false
            infoLabel.text = "\"applelogo\" system image - with trimmed empty-space bounding-box."
        case 2:
            myOutlineView.isHidden = false
            shapeLayer.opacity = 1.0
            infoLabel.text = "Dotted outline shape using Vision detected path."
        case 3:
            myOutlineView.isHidden = true
            myGradientView.isHidden = false
            infoLabel.text = "Use Dotted outline shape as a gradient layer mask."
        case 4:
            trimmedImageView.isHidden = true
            view.backgroundColor = .black
            infoLabel.text = "View by itself with Dotted outline shape as a gradient layer mask."
        default:
            view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
            defaultImageView.isHidden = false
            trimmedImageView.isHidden = true
            myOutlineView.isHidden = true
            myGradientView.isHidden = true
            shapeLayer.opacity = 0.0
            infoLabel.text = "Default \"applelogo\" system image - note empty-space bounding-box."
        }
    }

    func pathSetup() -> CGPath? {
        // get the cgPath from the image
        guard let cgPth = detectVisionContours(from: self.trimmedImage)
        else {
            print("Failed to get path!")
            return nil
        }
        
        // cgPath returned from Vision will be in rect 0,0 1.0,1.0 coordinates
        //  so we want to scale the path to our view bounds
        let scW: CGFloat = myOutlineView.bounds.width / cgPth.boundingBox.width
        let scH: CGFloat = myOutlineView.bounds.height / cgPth.boundingBox.height
        
        // we need to invert the Y-coordinate space
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            .scaledBy(x: scW, y: -scH)
            .translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -cgPth.boundingBox.height)
        
        return cgPth.copy(using: &transform)
    }
    
    func detectVisionContours(from sourceImage: UIImage) -> CGPath? {
        
        let inputImage = CIImage.init(cgImage: sourceImage.cgImage!)
        
        let contourRequest = VNDetectContoursRequest.init()
        contourRequest.revision = VNDetectContourRequestRevision1
        contourRequest.contrastAdjustment = 1.0
        contourRequest.maximumImageDimension = 512
        
        let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler.init(ciImage: inputImage, options: [:])
        try! requestHandler.perform([contourRequest])
        if let contoursObservation = contourRequest.results?.first {
            return contoursObservation.normalizedPath
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: trimming the image and UIImage quirks is what I was missing after all. I've posted my own answer below using SwiftUI, since that's what I originally set out to do. Thanks.

Comment: @technusm1 - whoops... yeah, I do very little with SwiftUI and fully intended to start my answer with "This needs to be adapted...". Glad it got you on your way :)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the Vision contour detection isn't a bad approach after all. I was just missing a few things, as helpfully pointed out by @DonMag. Here's my final answer using SwiftUI, in case someone's interested.

First, we create an `InsettableShape`:

```swift
struct MKSymbolShape: InsettableShape {
    var insetAmount = 0.0
    let systemName: String
    
    var trimmedImage: UIImage {
        let cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 256.0)
        // get the symbol
        guard let imgA = UIImage(systemName: systemName, withConfiguration: cfg)?.withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal) else {
            fatalError("Could not load SF Symbol: \(systemName)!")
        }
        
        // we want to "strip" the bounding box empty space
        // get a cgRef from imgA
        guard let cgRef = imgA.cgImage else {
            fatalError("Could not get cgImage!")
        }
        // create imgB from the cgRef
        let imgB = UIImage(cgImage: cgRef, scale: imgA.scale, orientation: imgA.imageOrientation)
            .withTintColor(.black, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
        
        // now render it on a white background
        let resultImage = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imgB.size).image { ctx in
            UIColor.white.setFill()
            ctx.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: imgB.size))
            imgB.draw(at: .zero)
        }
        
        return resultImage
    }
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        // cgPath returned from Vision will be in rect 0,0 1.0,1.0 coordinates
        //  so we want to scale the path to our view bounds
        
        let inputImage = self.trimmedImage
        guard let cgPath = detectVisionContours(from: inputImage) else { return Path() }
        let scW: CGFloat = (rect.width - CGFloat(insetAmount)) / cgPath.boundingBox.width
        let scH: CGFloat = (rect.height - CGFloat(insetAmount)) / cgPath.boundingBox.height
        
        // we need to invert the Y-coordinate space
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            .scaledBy(x: scW, y: -scH)
            .translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: -cgPath.boundingBox.height)
        
        if let imagePath = cgPath.copy(using: &transform) {
            return Path(imagePath)
        } else {
            return Path()
        }
    }
    
    func inset(by amount: CGFloat) -> some InsettableShape {
        var shape = self
        shape.insetAmount += amount
        return shape
    }
    
    func detectVisionContours(from sourceImage: UIImage) -> CGPath? {
        let inputImage = CIImage.init(cgImage: sourceImage.cgImage!)
        let contourRequest = VNDetectContoursRequest()
        contourRequest.revision = VNDetectContourRequestRevision1
        contourRequest.contrastAdjustment = 1.0
        contourRequest.maximumImageDimension = 512
        
        let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: inputImage, options: [:])
        try! requestHandler.perform([contourRequest])
        if let contoursObservation = contourRequest.results?.first {
            return contoursObservation.normalizedPath
        }
        
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then we create our main view:

```swift
struct PreviewView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            LinearGradient(colors: [.black, .purple], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            MKSymbolShape(systemName: "applelogo")
                .stroke(LinearGradient(colors: [.yellow, .orange, .pink, .red], startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 8, lineCap: .round, dash: [2.0, 21.0]))
                .aspectRatio(CGSize(width: 30, height: 36), contentMode: .fit)
                .padding()
        }
    }
}
```

Final look:
[image: Final look]