# How to draw an outline around a shape that grows externally in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, border, shapes, outline

Imagine this scenario:

1. You obtained a custom shape path (for instance [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181654/stroke-image-border-in-swiftui)), but one of the default shapes will do as well.
2. You want to draw the outline of that shape, with a `lineWidth` that depends on some `@State` variable
3. The outline must grow externally so that even when it gets too big, it doesn't lose its contour's shape
4. The inner fill is possibly transparent, for what matters.

So, I can't use `strokeBorder<S>(_ content: S, lineWidth: CGFloat = 1)` since its outline is centered on the actual contour of the path, as [per documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/insettableshape/strokeborder(_:linewidth:antialiased:)-5qhjc/).

Also can't use `stroke<S>(_ content: S, lineWidth: CGFloat = 1)` (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/shape/stroke(_:linewidth:))) since the effect is apparently just about the same, the outline is drawn centered.

An example code snippet reproducing the issue is the following:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var outlineSize: CGFloat = 1

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .stroke(.red, lineWidth: self.outlineSize)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            
            Slider(value: self.$outlineSize, in: 1...10)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding an overlay to the circle where the overlay contains the border?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var outlineSize: CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Circle()
                .fill(.white)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .overlay(
                    Circle()
                        .stroke(.red, lineWidth: self.outlineSize)
                        .frame(width: 100 + outlineSize, height: 100 + outlineSize)
                    )
            
            Slider(value: self.$outlineSize, in: 1...10)
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to adjust the frame of the circle, but this changes the behaviour slightly where the circle frame expands and affects other views.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var outlineSize: CGFloat = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Circle()
                .stroke(.red, lineWidth: self.outlineSize)
                .frame(width: 100 + outlineSize, height: 100 + outlineSize)
            
            Slider(value: self.$outlineSize, in: 1...10)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @yawnbleix: I had better luck adding a padding of `outlineSize/2` to the inner view. However this didn't suit well my purpose because I need it for much more complex paths than a circle, and redraws make the app stutter very badly.