How do I get a Path from an Image( )?
I can't find a way to do this but this code shows the concept of what I'm trying to do.  I need to draw the system image into a shape.
struct MyNoOp: Shape {
    var drawInfo: DrawInfo
    var iconName: String

    init(_ drawInfo: DrawInfo,_ iconName: String) {
        self.drawInfo = drawInfo
        self.iconName = iconName
    }

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path( )
        path.addPath(Image( systemName: iconName).path(in: rect))
        return path
    }
}


Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74181654/stroke-image-border-in-swiftui

@vadian this is NOT related since what you pointed out provides a view... not a PATH.

How about this: https://maheepk.net/posts/converting-sf-symbols-to-shapes/

I'll take a look at the new link please note though that the original link does not compile and is overly complicated.  I tried to import UIKit but got this.  No such module 'UIKit'.  My project is a SWiftUI project.

@vadian Also very complicated but doesn't give you the completed path.  Provides an outer outline and misses the internal pieces.  These system icons are simple not graphics like the pickachu.   It works for the Apple logo since everything is outside.  Just looking for something simple that will compile in my SwiftUI project.

@Rob Hey Rob TY.  I'm not looking for edge detection since that would miss the center of the icon.  Take a look at  plumbing for instance.  The bottom of the tank and other details would be missed.  I have a series of drawing objects that extend a shape and returns a path to draw (func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path).  In this case I want to display the given SF Symbol at the user given size.  For now... I'm using this draw objects that I have not yet implemented... a couple of dozen types.  In the long run I have future purposes for it for external 2d and 3d drawing types.

Ugg... so sorry that was my internal name the icon is toilet.  Can you show me an example then what the output was and how you called it?  On the trash can did you get all the vertical lines?  2 outer and 3 inner lines.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I would suggest that you do not want to create a path from an Image (which is a “view” type), but rather from NSImage/UIImage. So here is a routine to create a CGPath from a system symbol using the Vision framework’s “detect contours” routine from aNSImage/UIImage:
//  CGPath+Contour.swift
//
//  Created by Robert Ryan on 4/20/24.

#if os(macOS)
import AppKit.NSImage
typealias ImageType = NSImage
typealias Weight = NSFont.Weight
typealias Scale = NSImage.SymbolScale
#else
import UIKit.UIImage
typealias ImageType = UIImage
typealias Weight = UIImage.SymbolWeight
typealias Scale = UIImage.SymbolScale
#endif

import Vision

extension CGPath {
    static func contourPath(
        forSystemName systemName: String,
        pointSize: CGFloat,
        weight: Weight = .regular,
        scale: Scale = .small
    ) throws -> CGPath {
        guard
            let image = ImageType.system(
                named: systemName,
                pointSize: pointSize,
                weight: weight,
                scale: scale,
                foreground: .black
            )?
                .withBackground(.white),
            let cgImage = image.cgImage
        else {
            throw ContourError.imageNotFound
        }

        return try cgImage.contourPath(size: image.size)
    }
}

extension CGImage {
    func contourPath(size: CGSize? = nil, contrastAdjustment: Float = 2, maximumImageDimension: Int? = nil) throws -> CGPath {
        let size = size ?? CGSize(width: width, height: height)

        let contourRequest = VNDetectContoursRequest()
        contourRequest.maximumImageDimension = maximumImageDimension ?? Int(max(size.width, size.height))
        contourRequest.contrastAdjustment = contrastAdjustment
        let requestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: self, options: [:])
        try requestHandler.perform([contourRequest])
        var transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: CGFloat(size.height))
            .scaledBy(x: CGFloat(size.width), y: -CGFloat(size.height))
        guard let path = contourRequest.results?.first?.normalizedPath.mutableCopy(using: &transform) else {
            throw ContourError.noContour
        }
        return path
    }
}

enum ContourError: Error {
    case imageNotFound
    case noContour
}

#if os(macOS)

private extension NSImage {
    var cgImage: CGImage? {
        var rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        return cgImage(forProposedRect: &rect, context: nil, hints: nil)
    }

    static func createImage(size: NSSize, drawingHandler: (NSGraphicsContext) -> Void) -> NSImage? {
        let image = NSImage(size: size)
        image.lockFocus()
        defer { image.unlockFocus() }

        guard let context = NSGraphicsContext.current else {
            return nil
        }

        drawingHandler(context)

        return image
    }

    static func system(
        named systemName: String,
        pointSize: CGFloat,
        weight: NSFont.Weight = .regular,
        scale: SymbolScale = .medium,
        foreground: NSColor
    ) -> NSImage? {
        let configuration = Self.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: pointSize, weight: weight, scale: scale)
            .applying(.init(paletteColors: [foreground]))

        return NSImage(systemSymbolName: systemName, accessibilityDescription: nil)?
            .withSymbolConfiguration(configuration)
    }

    func withBackground(_ color: NSColor) -> NSImage? {
        NSImage.createImage(size: size) { context in
            let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
            NSColor.white.setFill()
            NSBezierPath(rect: rect).fill()
            draw(in: rect)
        }
    }
}

#else

extension UIImage {
    static func system(
        named systemName: String,
        pointSize: CGFloat,
        weight: SymbolWeight = .regular,
        scale: SymbolScale = .default,
        foreground: UIColor
    ) -> UIImage? {
        UIImage(
            systemName: systemName,
            withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: pointSize, weight: weight, scale: scale)
        )?
            .withTintColor(foreground, renderingMode: .alwaysOriginal)
    }

    func withBackground(_ background: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.scale = scale

        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect, format: format).image { _ in
            background.setFill()
            UIBezierPath(rect: rect).fill()
            draw(in: rect)
        }
    }
}

#endif

Now you can use that CGPath routine any way you want, e.g.:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
            if let cgPath = try? CGPath.contourPath(forSystemName: "trash.circle", pointSize: 256) {
                Path(cgPath)
                    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 3)
                    .frame(
                        width: cgPath.boundingBoxOfPath.maxX + cgPath.boundingBoxOfPath.minX,
                        height: cgPath.boundingBoxOfPath.maxY + cgPath.boundingBoxOfPath.minY
                    )
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

That is both the macOS and iOS rendition.
Note, contour detection does not appear to sense a change of alpha as an edge, so I render the system symbol in a high-contrast image (black on white), and then scan for contours in that.
That yields on macOS:

Or on iOS:

I threw this together, and there are tons of refinements I might contemplate, but hopefully, this is enough to get you going.

For the sake of future readers, we must recognize it is an inherently inefficient and imprecise technique to take what is, essentially, a vector asset, rendering it to a bitmap, and the detecting contours/edges within that image.
Generally, if I want a vector-based system image, I will often pull the SVG from the SF Symbols app, and then do what I need from there. This avoids runtime computational overhead and is far more precise. The OP could not do that in their particular use-case, but just a disclaimer on the above code.

Cool @Rob with a few changes I got my icons drawn (pen/fill colors, upper position).  I'm working on height & width.  Coordinate system seams to be different then Swift Paths (objects ended up off screen).  The imagines draw a few pixels down and to the right not sure why that happens.  One last issue I have a function that returns a Swift Image (returning images in my resources or  SF Symbols.  Is there a way to use that function instead.  In my case I'd rather the function silently fail when it can't find something or possibly just write out an error.

For the record, I'd rather pull the paths directly from the SF Symbols and drop those paths into my document but it appears that Swift doesn't have a way to do that.  I'd expect something like Image( systemName: iconName).path(in: rect) or getPath( systemName: iconName ) or other such vector based method.

Comments are not intended for extended conversations. So I’ll address your comments here in our existing chat.
