Why does UIImage with SymbolConfiguration change UIImageView frame?
I am making UIImageView with UIImage.SymbolConfiguration.
let config = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(font: .preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1))
imageView.image = UIImage(systemName: "person", withConfiguration: config)

Then setting up constraints:
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55.0),
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 55.0),

But instead I see frame is (8 10.3333; 55 51) instead of (8 10.3333; 55 55).
Why is this and how to fix it?

You need to show the code in context. Where is the code to create the image view and set its constraints? Where/when are you checking the image view's frame?

@HangarRash context is not important

You may find some help reviewing the discussions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224328/uiimageview-in-uicollectionviewcell-randomly-changing-frame-when-using-sf-symbol/66293917#66293917 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71701218/sf-symbol-does-not-work-well-with-scaleaspectfill

One solution could be to use the insets from the image view to offset the position, canceling it out.
Another is to make an image view subclass that always returns .zero.
