Using Symbol in UIImageView automatically resizes the UIImageView size
I am using Simple UIImageView in my code and setting image from symbols. The problem is once I've set symbol, the UIImageView doesn't care about NSLayoutConstrains and It's resizes as it wants.
Is there any way to fix this?
import UIKit

func Image(_ name: String, weight: UIImage.SymbolWeight, scale: UIImage.SymbolScale) -> UIImage {
    
    let configuration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: weight)
        .applying(UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: scale))
    return UIImage(named: name, in: nil, with: configuration)!
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
    
        let view = UIImageView()
        self.view.addSubview(view)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let size: CGFloat = 64
       
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        
            view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 8),
            view.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size),
            view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size)
        ])
 
        view.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2
        
        view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        imageView.tintColor = .black
        imageView.image = Image("info", weight: .light, scale: .small)
        
    }
}

I want perfect round but it's not,


It's perfect circle when using your code.

Why not add the icon inside a UIView and make the UIView circle? I think it better than make the icon round itself.

@kakaiikaka, I'm usisng simulator iOS 15.5 iPhone 12 Pro. It's not perfect circle when the size is small as I used. Which one of the version xcode and simulator you've tested?

@RattanakoudomSambath, Yes we can but that's not a solution. Right now I am using UIButton with userinteractionEnabled false. I want solution to use UIImageView.

@Vin this is correct view.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2, but not sure why view appears like that. if the size is fixed 64, as workaround just change view.layer.cornerRadius = 30 or something lesser

If you add 6 points to the height it'll completely circle, I've tried clipToBound and maskToBounds but nothing work actually, I think the problem is the image itself, if you using other png it working fine, but when using image from symbol it pinch like that.

@Vin -- Take a look at these discussions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224328/uiimageview-in-uicollectionviewcell-randomly-changing-frame-when-using-sf-symbol/66293917#66293917 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71701218/sf-symbol-does-not-work-well-with-scaleaspectfill
