UIImageView + SF Symbol size not consistent even thought I have provide width and height explicitly
Currently, I already specific the width and height for UIImageView explicitly. They are 80x80

However, when I compare 2 SF Symbols

mic
textformat

They have very different height

Does anyone know how I can achieve same width and same height for different SF Symbols?
In my UIImageView, both are using the same set of configurations (Aspect Fit)

Thank you.

Different symbols have different aspect ratios. If you want to respect their aspect ratios, then you cannot have symbols that are the same width and same height. Or do you just mean you want the red backgrounds to align?

You would have thought that “aspect fit” content mode would have fixed this, but it doesn’t in this case. Worst case, you can add another view behind this of the right size, with the same background color, and that will hide this weird UIImageView frame issue. Good question.

That having been said, not only do different symbols have different ratios, but they have completely difference sizes for the same font point size, too. Using a fixed sized image view with “aspect fit” content mode will end up resizing the symbols at different amounts, lending mismatched apparent weights. You might consider using a fixed point size “configuration” with “center” content mode, so that the multiple symbols appear with the relative size/weight as originally intended. This doesn’t solve the aspect ratio problem, but something to consider…

These answers may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66293917/6257435 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/71743787/6257435

@CheokYanCheng -- Are you still trying to work this out?

First, a little background...
From Apple's description (bold, italic emphasis mine):

SF Symbols is a library of over 6,000 symbols that are designed to integrate seamlessly with San Francisco, the system font for Apple platforms. Symbols come in nine weights and three scales, automatically align with text, and can be exported and edited using vector graphics editing tools to create custom symbols with shared design characteristics and accessibility features.

So, if we generate these 5 symbols:
"mic", "abc", "exclamationmark", "space", "circle"

using this configuration (point-size of 53.25 because it creates an 80x80 image of the "circle" symbol):
let cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 53.25, weight: .regular, scale: .large)
let img = UIImage(systemName: s, withConfiguration: cfg)

and then create 5 image views, constraining the Tops to the Top of the light-gray container view (with constant: 0.0), and the leading of each 8-points from the trailing of the previous one -- but NO width or height constraints... it looks like this:

As we see, UIKit is setting the image view widths, heights and y-offsets to automatically layout the symbols in a "font-like" fashion, resulting in these sizes and offsets (running on a @2x scale device, so we don't have to deal with .33333333 sizing):
                       Image Size        ImageView Size     Origin.y
                    -----------------   -----------------   --------
mic:                ( 67.00 x  83.50)   ( 67.00 x  83.50)    -12.50
abc:                (146.50 x  62.00)   (146.50 x  62.00)      1.00
exclamationmark:    ( 25.50 x  76.00)   ( 25.50 x  76.00)     -6.00
space:              ( 96.50 x  32.50)   ( 96.50 x  32.50)     26.00
circle:             ( 80.00 x  80.00)   ( 80.00 x  80.00)     -8.00

If, instead, we generate the images without point-size configuration:
let cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
let img = UIImage(systemName: s, withConfiguration: cfg)

and then create 5 image views, again constraining the Tops to the Top of the light-gray container view (with constant: 0.0), and the leading of each 8-points from the trailing of the previous one -- but this time WITH 80-point width and height constraints, we get this:

and these sizes and offsets:
                       Image Size        ImageView Size     Origin.y
                    -----------------   -----------------   --------
mic:                ( 21.00 x  27.00)   ( 80.00 x  87.00)     -4.50
abc:                ( 46.50 x  20.00)   ( 80.00 x  80.00)      0.00
exclamationmark:    (  8.00 x  24.50)   ( 80.00 x  84.50)     -2.00
space:              ( 30.50 x  11.00)   ( 80.00 x  71.00)      7.50
circle:             ( 26.00 x  26.00)   ( 80.00 x  86.00)     -3.00

So, UIKit is taking the "character" information from the symbol images and auto-adjusting the heights and y-origins of the image views to continue the "font-like" layout.
To get true non-resizing / non-offsetting image views, we need to subclass UIImageView and override alignmentRectInsets:
override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
    return .zero
}

Now we can get the desired image view framing:

                       Image Size        ImageView Size     Origin.y
                    -----------------   -----------------   --------
mic:                ( 21.00 x  27.00)   ( 80.00 x  80.00)      0.00
abc:                ( 46.50 x  20.00)   ( 80.00 x  80.00)      0.00
exclamationmark:    (  8.00 x  24.50)   ( 80.00 x  80.00)      0.00
space:              ( 30.50 x  11.00)   ( 80.00 x  80.00)      0.00
circle:             ( 26.00 x  26.00)   ( 80.00 x  80.00)      0.00


Here's a complete example that will display the 3 different layouts:
class MySymImgView: UIImageView {
    override var alignmentRectInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        return .zero
    }
}

class SymSizeVC: UIViewController {
    
    var pointSizeImages: [UIImage] = []
    var nonSizedImages: [UIImage] = []
    
    var nativeSizeImgViews: [UIImageView] = []
    var constrainedImgViews: [UIImageView] = []
    var subClassedImgViews: [MySymImgView] = []
    
    let nativeContainer = UIView()
    let constrainedContainer = UIView()
    let subclassedContainer = UIView()
    
    let ptSize: CGFloat = 53.25
    var boxSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    let symbolNames: [String] = [
        "mic", "abc", "exclamationmark", "space", "circle",
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        
        
        // symbol configuration with point-size
        var cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: ptSize, weight: .regular, scale: .large)
        
        for s in symbolNames {
            guard let img = UIImage(systemName: s, withConfiguration: cfg)
            else { fatalError("Could not create images!") }
            
            pointSizeImages.append(img)
            
            // let's use the circle symbol (configured with point size) as the size for the constrained image views
            if s == "circle" {
                boxSize = img.size
            }
        }
        
        // scale-only symbol configuration
        cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
        
        for s in symbolNames {
            guard let img = UIImage(systemName: s, withConfiguration: cfg)
            else { fatalError("Could not create images!") }
            
            nonSizedImages.append(img)
        }
        
        
        for (psImg, nsImg) in zip(pointSizeImages, nonSizedImages) {
            
            // image view with point-sized SFSymbol image
            let v1 = UIImageView(image: psImg)
            v1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            v1.backgroundColor = .init(UIColor(red: 0.828, green: 0.282, blue: 0.242, alpha: 1.0))
            v1.tintColor = .white
            v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            nativeSizeImgViews.append(v1)
            
            // image view with non-sized SFSymbol image
            let v2 = UIImageView(image: nsImg)
            v2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            v2.backgroundColor = .init(UIColor(red: 0.828, green: 0.282, blue: 0.242, alpha: 1.0))
            v2.tintColor = .white
            v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            constrainedImgViews.append(v2)
            
            // subclassed image view with non-sized SFSymbol image
            let v3 = MySymImgView(image: nsImg)
            v3.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            v3.backgroundColor = .init(UIColor(red: 0.828, green: 0.282, blue: 0.242, alpha: 1.0))
            v3.tintColor = .white
            v3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            subClassedImgViews.append(v3)
            
        }
        
        // add native size image views to container
        //  constrain all to Top
        //  constrain first leading to container leading + 20-points
        //  constrain each leading to previous trailing + 8-points
        for (i, v) in nativeSizeImgViews.enumerated() {
            nativeContainer.addSubview(v)
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nativeContainer.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            if i == 0 {
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nativeContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
            } else {
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nativeSizeImgViews[i - 1].trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
            }
        }
        
        // add non-sized image views to container
        //  constrain all to Top
        //  constrain first leading to container leading + 20-points
        //  constrain each leading to previous trailing + 8-points
        //  constrain all with width & height
        for (i, v) in constrainedImgViews.enumerated() {
            constrainedContainer.addSubview(v)
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: constrainedContainer.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            if i == 0 {
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: constrainedContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
            } else {
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: constrainedImgViews[i - 1].trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
            }
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: boxSize.width).isActive = true
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: boxSize.height).isActive = true
        }
        
        // add subclassed image views to container
        //  constrain all to Top
        //  constrain first leading to container leading + 20-points
        //  constrain each leading to previous trailing + 8-points
        //  constrain all with width & height
        for (i, v) in subClassedImgViews.enumerated() {
            subclassedContainer.addSubview(v)
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subclassedContainer.topAnchor, constant: 0.0).isActive = true
            if i == 0 {
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subclassedContainer.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
            } else {
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subClassedImgViews[i - 1].trailingAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
            }
            v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: boxSize.width).isActive = true
            v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: boxSize.height).isActive = true
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // setup and constrain container views
        for v in [nativeContainer, constrainedContainer, subclassedContainer] {
            v.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
            
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
                v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
                v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: boxSize.height),
            ])
            
            if v == nativeContainer {
                v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0).isActive = true
            } else if v == constrainedContainer {
                v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nativeContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
            } else {
                v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: constrainedContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
            }
        }
        
    }
    
}

Note: the layout is too wide for a phone in Portrait orientation.
